# getJSON com parsererror

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, codeigniter

Estou tentando realizar a exclusão e um item, para isso no `controller` mando um código para `view` **0** ou **1**, porém o a função JS responsável por tratar esse retorno esta sempre caindo no `fail` com o seguinte erro.

> error [object Object] parsererror

---

**Controller**

```
if ($this->matricula_model->excluir($matricula) === true)
   echo json_encode(['codigo' => '0']);
else
   echo json_encode(['codigo' => '1']);
```

Se o retorno for true (não houve na exclusão) retorna **0**, se não **1**. No getJSON eu precisava capturar esse 0 e 1 para mostrar uma mensagem, mas só obtenho o erro.

**getJSON**

```
$.getJSON($('#base-url').val() + '/matricula/excluir/' + sf, function(data) {
   console.log( "success", data );
  })
 .fail(function(textStatus, errorThrown) {
   console.log("error " + textStatus, errorThrown);
})
```

Comment: Adicionou o header? `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: Sim, já esta configurado isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, você pode tentar o seguinte:

```
if ($this->matricula_model->excluir($matricula) === true)
 echo json_encode(array('codigo' => '0'));
else
 echo json_encode(array('codigo' => '1'));
```

ou também

```
if ($this->matricula_model->excluir($matricula) === true)
 echo json_encode((object)['codigo' => '0']);
else
 echo json_encode((object)['codigo' => '1']);
```

array () ou o (object) servem respectivamente para forçar que esse JSON seja um array ou objeto.

espero que ajude :D

Comment: Infelizmente sem sucesso com ambas.

Comment: hmm, já tentou ver como o seu JSON está sendo criado? para ver se ele está sendo criado corretamente?

Comment: Esta do seguinte formato. {"codigo":"1"}

Comment: $('#base-url').val() + '/matricula/excluir/' + sf está seria sua url correto? vc consegue acessar ela para ver oque ela retorna? ja tentou usar apenas $.get()?

Comment: Sim é a URL correta, ela vai me retornar um erro porém o erro é do DELETE que não pode ser feito pq existe referencias da coluna em outra tabela.

Comment: Porém em caso desse erro ele deveria me retornar o código 1 para mim informar ao usuário que houve um erro na exclusão.

Comment: acho que voce ja deve ter tentado criar o JSON e atribuir em um variavel e ai mandar para echo ? $var = (object) ["cad" => 1]; echo json_encode($var);

Comment: Sim já havia tentado, assim funciona kkk

Comment: kkkk bah que coisa

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON($('#base-url').val() + '/matricula/excluir/' + sf, function(data) {

   // tente modificar inserir isso antes do console.log
   var data = JSON.parse(data);
   console.log( "success", data );

 })

 .fail(function(textStatus, errorThrown) {
   console.log("error " + textStatus, errorThrown);
})
```

Comment: Sem sucesso, continua com o mesmo erro.

Comment: Ele cai direto no `fail`. Sem sucesso.